# new and static used at once in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I encounter with one strange line of code in the larvel 5.0

```
echo (new static)->getMorphClass();
```

This echo the namespace of the model. Now didn't understand how come `new` and `static` are used at once.

> PHP version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 0):

`new static` is just a php construct and has nothing to do with Laravel. The `static` keyword references the **current class**, so `new static` is **nothing more than a call to the current class constructor**.

Consider this example:

```
class Cat {
    private function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public static function getACat($newType)
    {
        return new static($newType); // same as 'return new Cat($newType);'
    }

    public function print()
    {
        echo $this->type;
    }
}

$cat1 = Cat::getACat("Fatty");
$cat1->print(); // --> Fatty
```